# Why is 0x7E commonly used as Start Delimiter in Communication Protocol?

Tags: serial-port, serial-communication, xbee

i am looking to implement a serial communication between 2 devices using just a simple communication.

It seem that protocol such as those used in HDLC and xBee uses **0x7E** as the start delimiter.

Is there any particular reason or i can use any character as an alternative.

Comment: Are you using AT mode or API mode? 0x7E is only the starting delimiter for API mode, and in that case you have to construct packets according to the User's Guide.

Comment: Hi , i wasnt using xBee. i am just curious why is 0x7E selected as the start delimiter.

Comment: Okay. Well if you use the default communication method, which is AT mode, no delimiters are necessary.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason is related to framing of data.

- They needed a flag that will mark a beginning and an end of transmission.
- They wanted to be able to replicate that flag few times if needed - in example if you send 
  01111110 01111110 01111110 - it is very easy to identify this set compared to other sets even if some bits didn't made it to the other side, so it is uniquely much less error prone.
  (0x7E=01111110)

**Extended Example:**

machine 1 sent: `01111110 01111110 01111110` 
some options for error in receive:
machine 2 recv: `011110011111001111110` - notice that you can identify 3 frames very easy.
machine 2 recv: `11111001111110011111` - again you can identify 3 frames quite easy. 
machine 2 recv: `01111110111111001111110` - once more 3 frames can be identified quite easy.

**Now let's see what happens if we choose different sequences as flags.**

*Example 1:*

machine 1 sent: `01011010 01011010 01011010` (here flag chosen is `01011010`)
 
some options for error in receive:
machine 2 recv: `010010100101101001011010` - you cannot identify if those are even frames..

*Example2:*

machine 1 sent: `00011000 00011000 00011000` (here flag chosen is `00011000`)
 
some options for error in receive:
machine 2 recv: `00110000001100000011000` - this one is ok... we can easy see 3 frames.. but..
machine 2 recv: `0010000001100000011000` - this is harder.. could be 3 frames but can't be sure..

You can read more in [Wikipedia information about HDLC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-Level_Data_Link_Control) (check the frames subject)

One more thing.. *SO Folks I know this has a flame potential :) 

Please keep in mind I didn't choose this arbiter sequence.. I only explain the reason for this particular sequence as choice.*

Comment: Having once (a long time ago) worked on protocols for serial magnetic tape I can say that what you say is true, but there are a few other considerations as well, of a similar nature.

Comment: @HotLicks I'm aware of those too.. but if I included those in my answer.. the amount of "flame-potential" would be much higher :)
And, I would like to buy you a beer if we ever meet.

Comment: seems 0x3c would be better for this purpose (or 0x3e for that matter).  and one can even work out the exact best # assuming all bits have equal prob of being dropped (and it is probably not 0x7e)..  why use 0x7e?

Comment: @thang I believe the assumption is incorrect.. a 1 is much likely to be dropped than 0.. to transmit 1 - a pulse need to arrive from one side to the other but to transmit 0 - nothing need to arrive.. yet something can be spiked in some cases - but it is less to happen.. also the occurance of ~ as data is statistical less than <.. but please don't make me defend it :)

Comment: Hi G.Y , your answer is great. Just wondering if there is there a reason why dont we used something which does not appear on the ascii table such as 0x81 1000 0001 ?

Comment: @sean if 0x81 is used in 8bit frames which means we "parallel" 8bit ascii table (or the extended ascii table) - then it does appear in ascii table.. but if used in 7bit frames it means 2 frames are used to recognize the signal in your example.. so it is actually going to look like 1000000 1000000 - which is probably longer than needed and more error prone.

Comment: i think that in all likelihood, anything that is a few zeros, a bunch of 1s, and a few zeros (or the ~ of it) would work.  they probably picked 0x7e because it's not likely to be used often in the stream (and 7-bit).  0x7e is also used as an ESC code.  not sure I buy the 1 more likely to be dropped than 0 because a lot of times, the lines are inverted on the wire (e.g. RS-232).

Comment: @thang To me development is the application of 5774 years of evolved philosophy concepts in its most pure form expect perhaps the creation of this world itself.. so I cannot really be the dude to defend an arbiter or even slightly arbiter choice in coding :)